# Is it possible to include/exclude `cs`-file into the `csproj`-file by the `dotnet` command?

Tags: c#, .net-core

.Net Core 2

Is it possible to include/exclude `cs`-file into the `csproj`-file by the `dotnet` command? In the documentation I found only how to add a package to `csproj`-file by the `dotnet` command.

Comment: `.cs` files are included by default. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I know. I asked about the additional files.

Comment: It’s not something you can do with `dotnet`. If you can provide more information about the types of files and how they’re generated, there might be an alternative suggestion.

Comment: My code sources are located on the remote computer with Linux OS. From time to time it is convenient for me to work with it via `ssh`. At this case I use `vim` text editor that is installed on the remote machine. Of cource, I can open and edit `csproj`-file in `vim`, but it is interesting for me: Is it possible to perform the operation specified by me via `dotnet` (this program is installed on the remote machine too)...